# How to convert a Future[Seq[A]] to a Future that contains Seq[A]?

Tags: scala, finagle, finatra

I'm working on a Finatra app where I have a `Future[Seq[A]]` (from Finagle call). However, I need to convert that to a new object that contains `Seq[A]`, for example

```
case class Container[A](s: Seq[A])
```

That would result in `Future[Container]`.

While I can perform map on `Future[Seq[A]]`, it's unclear how to arrive at `Future[Container[Seq[A]]`.

Comment: I recommend reading http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.map` over the `Future` with `Container.apply`:

```
scala> case class Container[A](s: Seq[A])
defined class Container

scala> val f = Future.successful(List(1, 2, 3))
f: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@3f363cf5

scala> f.map(Container.apply)
res2: scala.concurrent.Future[Container[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3d829787

scala> res2.value
res3: Option[scala.util.Try[Container[Int]]] = Some(Success(Container(List(1, 2, 3))))
```

---

`f.map(Container.apply)` is short for `f.map(Container.apply(_))`, which in turn is short for `f.map(v => Container.apply(v))`.

Note that you could also write it `f.map(Container(_))`, whichever you prefer.

Comment: Great explanation! I was confusing the map functions between Seq and Future.